# Solving of three non-linear simultaneous differential equations with given boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve three simultaneous differential equations in *Mathematica*-10 but I am not able to get the solutions. After running the following command as I am pressing shift+enter it just simply shows the equation again:

My equations are:

```
{x1'[t]-w1[t]*l2*x2[t]-l1*(v-x1[t])==0,
x2'[t]+w1[t]*l1*x1[t]-l2*(v-x1[t])==0,
w1'[t]-k*x2[t]*(v-x1[t])==0}
```

with boundary conditions:

```
{x1[0]==0, x2[0]==0,w1[0]==15,x1[infinity]=v}
```

After solving these equations i need the values of `x1`, `x2`, and `w1`.

For solving these equations i ma running the following command:

```
DSolve[{
        x1'[t]-w1[t]*l2*x2[t]-l1*(v-x1[t])==0, 
        x2'[t]+w1[t]*l1*x1[t]-l2*(v-x1[t])==0, 
        w1'[t]-k*x2[t]*(v-x1[t])==0, 
        x1[0]==0,x2[0]==0, w1[0]==50, x1[Infinity]==v
       },{x1, x2, w1}, t]
```

Can anyone suggest me the correct answer of the above equations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I formatted your question. Please learn [how to do it your self](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see how to ask good questions.

Comment: `DSolve` will return an analytic solution. Are you sure such a solution exists?

Comment: Unless this is meant to be an eigenvalue problem, there is one too many boundary conditions for the third-order system of ODEs.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

As march suggested in a comment, it appears that `DSolve` cannot solve this problem.  However, quite a good analytical approximation can be obtained, as presented below.  First, however, it is useful to examine a numerical solution in order to gain insight.  Parameters `{l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}` are used here, although similar results are obtained for other choices, provided that the parameters are positive and somewhat less than `w1[0]`.

```
s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] - w1[t]*l2*x2[t] - l1*(v - x1[t]) == 0, 
     x2'[t] + w1[t]*l1*x1[t] - l2*(v - x1[t]) == 0, 
     w1'[t] - k*x2[t]*(v - x1[t]) == 0, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, 
     w1[0] == 50} /. {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}, 
     {x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}];
```

Multiple plots are needed to display the diverse scales present in the solution.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 5000}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, "x1, x2, w1"}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 5000}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.4, 1.2}}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x1, x2, w1"}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.1, .2}}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x1, x2, w1"}]
```

[image]

Two interesting features are immediately apparent.  First, `x1` is equal to `v` at large `t`, as desired by the OP, even without an imposed boundary condition there.  (This occurs only for positive `l1` and `l2`.)  Second, the characteristic timescale for variation of `x1` and `x2` is far shorter than that for `w1` before all three become essentially constant at late time.  This suggests that reasonably accurate expressions for `x1` and `x2` can be obtained ignoring the variation in `w1`.  For convenience, temporarily designate this quasi-constant quantity as `w0` and solve for the remaining variables.

```
s0 = FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[Flatten@DSolve[
    {x1'[t] - w0*l2*x2[t] - l1*(v - x1[t]) == 0, 
     x2'[t] + w0*l1*x1[t] - l2*(v - x1[t]) == 0, 
     x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t] /. 
     l1^2 - 4 l2^2 w0 - 4 l1 l2 w0^2 -> -c]]
(* {x1[t] -> (4 E^(-((l1 t)/2))
    l2 v w0 (Sqrt[c] E^((l1 t)/2) l2 - Sqrt[c] l2 Cos[(Sqrt[c] t)/2] +
    l1 (l2 + 2 l1 w0) Sin[(Sqrt[c] t)/2]))/(Sqrt[c] (c + l1^2)), 
    x2[t] -> (4 E^(-((l1 t)/2))
    v w0 (-Sqrt[c] E^((l1 t)/2) l1^2 + Sqrt[c] l1^2 Cos[(Sqrt[c] t)/2] + 
    (l1^3 + 2 l2^3 + 2 l1 l2^2 w0) Sin[(Sqrt[c] t)/2]))/(Sqrt[c] (c + l1^2))} *)
```

`c` also is introduced for ease of visualization and manipulation.  For `w0` somewhat larger than the other parameters, `c` is approximately equal to `4 l1 l2 w0^2`.  Now, obtain limiting expressions for `x1` and `x2` for times long compared their transient behavior.

```
MapAt[Limit[#, t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> l1 > 0 && c > 0] &, s0, {All, 2}];
suv = Simplify[% /. c -> -(l1^2 - 4 l2^2 w0 - 4 l1 l2 w0^2)] /. w0 -> w1[t]
(* {x1[t] -> (l2 v)/(l2 + l1 w1[t]), x2[t] -> -((l1^2 v)/(l2^2 + l1 l2 w1[t]))} *)
```

We now can obtain `w1`, again using `DSolve`.

```
First@DSolve[Simplify[w1'[t] - k*x2[t]*(v - x1[t]) == 0 /. suv], w1[t], t]
(* {w1[t] -> InverseFunction[l2^2 Log[#1] + 2 l1 l2 #1 + (l1^2 #1^2)/2 &]
    [-((k l1^3 t v^2)/l2) + C[1]]} *)
```

This would be a completely symbolic solution, except that `C[1]` can be obtained from `w1[0] == 50` only after the other parameters have been given numerical values.  For instance,

```
f = w1[t] /. % /. C[1] -> t0 /. {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1};
FindRoot[(f /. t -> 0) == 50, {t0, 1500}]
(* {t0 -> 1465.65} *)
```

with `C[1]` replaced by `t0` to keep `FindRoot` happy.

Alternatively, and more simply,

```
sw = First@DSolve[{Simplify[w1'[t] - k*x2[t]*(v - x1[t]) == 0 /. suv /. 
    {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}], w1[0] == 50}, w1[t], t]
(* {w1[t] -> InverseFunction[4 Log[#1] + 4 #1 + #1^2/2 &]
       [-(t/2) + 2 (725 + 2 Log[50])]} *)
```

Altogether, the mostly symbolic solution for this set of parameters is

```
{x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]} /. suv /. sw /. {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}
```

and plotting it, for instance by

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], w1[t]} /. suv /. sw /. {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}],
    {t, 0, 5000}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5000}, {-.4, 1.2}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

yields a curve indistinguishable to the eye from the second curve above.

**Addendum**

The results above are entirely symbolic except for the determination of `C[1]`, which employes `FindRoot`.  This constant can be obtained symbolically as well.  From the earlier analysis,

```
w1[t] /. First@DSolve[Simplify[w1'[t] - k*x2[t]*(v - x1[t]) == 0 /. suv], w1[t], t]
```

gives `w1[t]` as a function of `C[1] - ((k l1^3 t v^2)/l2)`.  Consequently, `C[1] - ((k l1^3 t v^2)/l2)` can be expressed as a function of `w1[t]` by

```
InverseFunction[Head[%]]
(* l2^2 Log[#1] + 2 l1 l2 #1 + (l1^2 #1^2)/2 & *)
```

which at `w1[0] = 50` yields `C[1]`

```
%[50]
(* 1250 l1^2 + 100 l1 l2 + l2^2 Log[50] *)
```

For the set of parameters, `{l1 -> 1, l2 -> 2, k -> 1, v -> 1}`, this equals `1450 + 4 Log[50]`, or `1465.65`, as computed previously.