# DSolve documention on web differs greatly from distributed MMA 10.2.0 version

Tags: differential-equations, documentation

In the course of improving my answer to [95361](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95728/1063), I noticed that the [`DSolve` documentation on the web](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) is much better written than that distributed with *Mathematica* 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015).  Moreover, it describes a more powerful version of `DSolve`, one that accepts `Assumptions` as an option and can solve Sturm-Liouvlle Problems, for instance.  My questions are

- Are this better version of `DSolve` and its documentation available for download?
- Do other functions have updated versions and documentation not part of the current release of Mathematica?
- Does documentation exist for `DSolve` `Method`?

Comment: At the bottom of the documentation distributed with *Mathematica* 10.2.0 one can find the information "Introduced in 1991 (2.0) | Updated in 2014 (10.0)". There isn't such an information on the web documentation, whereas such information is also available in the web documentation for other functions (for example for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)).

Comment: There are currently many updated Documentation Center pages on the WEI site that discuss new functionality and even new functions. I guess WRI is getting close to a new release. There was similar activity on the WRI site when V10 was near release.

Comment: In the web documentation, while the option `Method` appears under the `Details and Options` section, `Method` is not a listed option under the `Options` subsection of the `Examples` section.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - I was merely pointing out an inconsistency in the web documentation which presumably might indicate that the `Method` option and/or its documentation may not be finalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This improved version of `DSolve` and its documentation will be part of *Mathematica* 10.3 as can be seen in the [Summary of New Features in 10.3](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn103.html). There you'll also find which other functions will get updated and which new functions will be introduced. From my experience the web documentation for these functions will get updated prior to the release of the new version.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Method` option isn't well documented for too many functions.